# rails 3.1, how to define global constant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I tried to define a constant in `config\environments\development.rb`

```
NEXT_PAGE_ID = 'next_page'
```

but when I try to access it at a view I get this error

> uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::NEXT_PAGE_ID

I tried to define it at `/config/initializers/course_builder` like this:

```
NEXT_PAGE_ID = 'next_page'
```

but I got the same error.

Restarting the server didn't help. What can I do?

**Edit**

Here is the full error:

uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::NEXT_PAGE_ID

Extracted source (around line #23):

```
20:             %></li>
21: 
22:         <li><%= if @page.position < @page.chapter.pages.count then
23:             next_page= Page.find(Page.where(:position => @page.position+1, :chapter_id => @page.chapter.id))
24:             link_to 'Next Page', next_page, {:id=>NEXT_PAGE_ID}
25:             end
26:         %></li>
```

Comment: `course_builder` or `course_builder.rb`?

Comment: Paste the complete error please and how you are using NEXT_PAGE_ID. The error seems to indicate you might be using the constant incorrectly. Ideally you should be able to declare a constant in the initializers or the environment files.

Comment: Ok, the full error is in the question above.

Comment: okey! that's it, thanks Chowlett, the file should be course_builder.rb not course_builder, I forgot to add the extension, its working now :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a session variable instead. Globals are not needed in this case (or in most cases) and, evidently, problematic.

```
session[:current_page_id]
```

Or

```
session[:next_page_id]
```

Comment: NEXT_PAGE_ID is used for the ID of the href that is used as "Next Page", its always "next_page", its not an ID for a record.
Is there a better naming convention for an element at the page HTML DOM? 
I am still not able to use a global constant ..

Comment: If it's always that ID, then just type that ID in there instead of worrying about a constant... If you're not planning on changing something minuscule like that, there's no point in having a way to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
Object.const_set('NEXT_PAGE_ID', 'next_page')
```

But you should probably use some sort of configuration file for these kind of things instead of polluting the global namespace.